# Why are isometries all and only $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ :$f(x)=Nx+p$,where $N$ ortogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry

A passage in my notes reads:

> Isometries in metric spaces coincide with the usual ones when considering mappings $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $  with the respective Euclidean metrics.
>
> In particular, every isometry $f$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with itself is of the form $f(\vec{x})=N\vec{x} + \vec{p}$,where $N \in O(n)$ is an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix and $\vec{p} \in\mathbb{R}^n.$

**Can someone elaborate on this? Why do all isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ take  this form?**

Comment: I would love to see a proof that endows the reader with intuition, but I have not seen  one. Section 1-1 of [_Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds_](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Introduction_to_Differentiable_Manifolds/J98LQTpm0wIC) by Louis Auslander & Robert E. MacKenzie does offer an awkwardly-worded development that leads, more or less, to this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this argument works but please correct me if wrong, or if I made any assumptions.

Consider the function $g(x) = f(x) - f(0)$. If we show that $g$ is a linear isometry, then we are done. The isometry is trivial. $$||g(x) - g(y)|| = ||f(x) - f(0) - f(y) + f(0)|| = ||f(x) - f(y)|| = ||x-y||$$
The tricky part is showing linearity. Okay so, we immediately have $g(0) = f(0) - f(0) = 0$ so that's great. Let's also note that $g$ preserves norms of vectors. Indeed $||g(x)|| = ||f(x) - f(0)|| = ||x-0|| = ||x||$.

How do we show $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$? Let's try something slightly different. Let us show that $g(x-y) = g(x) - g(y)$. We can almost say it's the same as showing $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$ but remember we haven't shown that $g$ respects scalar multiplication yet! Now consider a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with two sides $x$ and $y$ (starting at the origin). Then $x-y$ represents the third side of the triangle. So $x, y, x-y$ as points, get mapped to $g(x), g(y), g(x-y)$. Crucially, this is also a triangle "based" at the origin (since the line segment from $0$ to $x$ gets mapped to the line segment between $0$ and $g(x)$). Note that since $g$ is an isometry, the triangle formed by these three points is congruent to the one formed by $x, y, x-y$. But saying this is *exactly* saying that $g(x-y) = g(x) - g(y)$.

Great, we're almost there. If we want to show that $g(ax) = ag(x)$, we again use a similar argument as before. Consider points $x$ and $ax$. The relevant "triangle" (actually a line here) is formed by $x, ax$ and $(a-1)x$. This gets mapped to a line and so we have $g(ax)$ and $g(x)$ are collinear (with the orientations preserved i.e. if $a > 0$ then they point in the same direction, and if $a < 0$ then they point in opposite directions). But moreover we also know that $||g(ax)|| = ||ax|| = |a| ||x||$ so in fact it preserves the scaling factor. These two facts combined give us $g(ax) = ag(x)$.

So we have shown that $g$ is a linear isometry so it's of the form $Nx$ for some $N \in O(n)$. So $f(x) - f(0) = Nx \implies f(x) = Nx + f(0) = Nx + p$.

The gist is isometries take the triangle formed by two vectors to another triangle formed by two vectors, and they are congruent. This congruency implies linearity of the "shifted" function. Even more generally, isometries always preserves lengths and angles (so they preserve the dot product). In fact you can generalize this by saying that the group of isometries on *any* normed vector space $V$ (whose metric is induced by the norm) is equal to $V \rtimes O(V)$.

Comment: Are you assuming f is an isometry at the very beginning?

Comment: "$g$ is a linear isometry so it's of the form $Nx$ for some $N \in O(n)$".... this is the part of the question, where do we get that orthogonal matrix from?

Comment: Yes I’m assuming $f$ is an isometry. The question is to show every isometry $f$ is of the given form. You don’t need to produce the orthogonal matrix $N$. It’s a standard linear algebraic fact that any linear isometry is given by an orthogonal matrix. A quick proof is that it preserves the inner product so $x^T A^T Ax = x^Tx$ so $A^T A = I$. The non-trivial part is showing that $g$ is a linear isometry itself. A priori, we barely know anything about $g$, let alone that it’s linear. Also if you want the matrix $N$ you can just look at the image of a basis under $g$.

Comment: Note that I’m distinguishing between an isometry and a linear isometry. I’m essentially saying that any isometry that fixes $0$ is linear.

Comment: "So $x, y, x-y$ as points, get mapped to $g(x), g(y), g(x-y)$"... Picturing this in a 2D plane for simplicity, x-y is not a point, but a vector, so I don't think we can say we can see as a point and map it.

Comment: I’m engaging in a bit of abuse of terminology. $x-y$ is a point too, it’s just nowhere to be seen on the triangle. Similarly for $g(x-y)$. The reason I talk about these points is to say $||x-y|| = ||g(x-y)||$ so the lengths of the third side of the triangle are the same. Perhaps it’s better reworded as the triangle with sides $x$, $y$ gets mapped to one with sides $g(x), g(y)$, and they are congruent.

Comment: Perhaps theorem 2.4 here https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/isometryRn.pdf is more to your style

Comment: This is good & intuitive, but I think it needs more rigor. You mix points and vectors, which needs more machinery to do properly. The original triangle is formed by the points $0$, $x$, $y$. The mapped triangle is formed by $g(0)=0$, $g(x)$, $g(y)$. There is a _point_ with coordinates equal to the entries of the _vector_ $x-y$, but you have no relation between the image of that point under $g$ and the _vector_ $g(x)-g(y)$. You might say that $x=x-0$ and $y=y-0$ are vectors, but they are anchored at 0, while the vector $x-y$ is anchored at $y$. Treating them the same is _assuming linearity_.